# Entity Type Configuration // Fluent API - mapping - zero to one foreignKey

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

I have a problem with mapping my classes using code first and Entity Type Configuration.

I have a class User

```
public class User
{
public virtual UserData UserData { get; set; }

public Guid UserId { get; set; }
public string UserName { get; set; }
public virtual string PasswordHash { get; set; }
public virtual string SecurityStamp { get; set; }
public string Email { get; set; }
```

which is a User Table. And a UserData - which will be a table contains UserData as Name, LastName etc.

I want to use UserId as Forgein Key one-to-zer-or-one. For one user there will be only one UserData

```
public class UserData
{

public long Id { get; set; }
public Guid UserId { get; set; }
public string FirstName { get; set; }
public string LastName { get; set; }

public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

But can't quite figure out how to do the mapping

```
internal UserConfiguration()
{
ToTable("User");

HasKey(x => x.UserId)
    .Property(x => x.UserId)
    .HasColumnName("UserId")
    .HasColumnType("uniqueidentifier")
    .IsRequired();

... properties mapping



HasOptional(x => x.UserData).
    WithRequired(x => x.User); ?? is this ok?
}
```

and the UserData

```
internal UserDataConfiguration()
        {
            ToTable("UserData");

            HasKey(x => x.Id)
                .Property(x => x.Id)
                .HasColumnName("Id")
                .HasColumnType("bigint")
                .IsRequired();

            Property(x => x.FirstName)
                .HasColumnName("FirstName")
                .HasColumnType("nvarchar")
                .HasMaxLength(255);

            Property(x => x.LastName)
                .HasColumnName("LastName")
                .HasColumnType("nvarchar");

            Property(x => x.UserId)
                .HasColumnName("UserId")
                .HasColumnType("uniqueidentifier")
                .IsRequired();
            ?? is this ok?


        }
```

Answer (score 1):

For `User` in `UserConfiguration()` to map one-to-zero-or-one relationship you can define as:

```
HasOptional(x => x.UserData).WithRequired(x => x.User);
```

Answer (score 1):

For a 1:0..1 relationship in Entity Framework, the primary key for the optional side is also the foreign key, so you can set it up like this:

```
UserConfiguration()
{
    ToTable("User");

    HasKey(x => x.UserId)
    Property(x => x.UserId)
        .HasColumnName("UserId")
        .HasColumnType("uniqueidentifier")
        .IsRequired();

    // you could define the relationship here as well, I moved it 
    // to UserDataConfiguration to make it easier to explain

    // other properties
}

UserDataConfiguration()
{
    ToTable("UserData");

    HasKey(x => x.UserId);

    Property(x => x.UserId)
        .HasColumnName("UserId")
        .HasColumnType("uniqueidentifier")
        .IsRequired();

    // This makes UserData's primary key the foreign key by default
    HasRequired(x => x.User).WithOptional(x => x.UserData);

    // other properties
}
```

You can't have a separate primary key for `UserData`.